# C#, LINQ не работает foreach

Tags: c#, linq

В списке, для каждого элемента пытаюсь установить значение. Но в отладчике видно, что список остается неизменным.

```
List<int> test_list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6};

test_list.ForEach(o => { o = 9; });
```

Comment: И не удивительно, вы получаете копию каждого элемента. LINQ вообще не предназначен для изменения элементов. Если вы хотите функциональный подход, просто сконструируйте новый список.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ForEach` предназначен для выполнения какого-то действия над каждым объектом списка. Он не предназначен и не может быть использован для изменения самих элементов(за исключением вызова модифицирующих методов). Ваш код можно переписать с использованием LINQ следующим образом(один из вариантов):

```
test_list = Enumerable.Repeat(9, test_list.Count).ToList();
```

Но, на мой взгляд, Ваш пример слишком надуманный и на самом деле у Вас задача шире, поэтому в общем виде это решается через `Select`:

```
test_list = test_list.Select(item => 9).ToList();
```

---

Если члены списка это некие структуры со свойствами ID и Status и нужно просто заменить один элемент, тогда это делается так:

```
var idx = test_list.FindIndex(item => item.ID == X);
if(idx != -1)
    test_list[idx] = new YourStruct(X, Y);
```

Если просто нужно изменить свойство, тогда вместо замены всего элемента — меняйте свойство.

Comment: На самом деле у меня список из структур. Структура имеет свойства: ID и Status. Мне необходимо у структуры с ID = X, изменить статус на Y. Как это сделать максимально эффективно?

Comment: @Dzam, обновил ответ

Comment: Согласен с for. Думаю не совсем корректно каждый раз из за изменения одного свойства одного элемента переписывать весь список. А возможно ли использовать такой подход:
int index = test_list.IndexOf(struct_element);
test_list[index].status = 9

Comment: @Dzam, Вы выдаёте задачу порциями. Надо было сразу всю. Надо было сразу сказать, что только один элемент изменяется и прочие данные

Comment: Хотел общий подход понять. Прошу прощения.

Comment: @Dzam, просто подходы могут быть разные, к разным задачам. Обновил ответ

Comment: @Dzam Правильно сделал, в общем и целом. Слишком часто здесь постят убер-специфичные вопросы, по сути просто бросаясь куском кода в духе «отдебажьте за меня этот кусок кода, вам же тут все равно всем нечем заняться».

Comment: @MaximKamalov, мне пришлось 3 раза редактировать ответ, потому что данные менялись. Я не спорю, не очень хорошо когда слишком узкие вопросы задают, но вопросы, данные которых раскрываются лишь в процессе, на мой взгляд, ничем не лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `for`

```
List<int> test_list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6};

for(int i = 0; i < test_list.Count; i++)
     test_list[i] = 9;
```